# Monitoring the applications on a server

Tags: mysql, ruby, rabbitmq, monitoring

I have a ruby script running a server 7 days a weeks 24 hours. It communicates with a third-party website and locally RabbitMQ and MySql. I want it to reliable, of course. I already have some solution for monitoring the ruby script, whether or not it's up, if it's not then the admin will be sent an email.

I wonder, should I also monitory the availability of RabbitMQ and MySql? Is that a good practice or would it be redundant? It might be redundant because if RabbitMQ and MySql is down, the script will also eventually go down and thus the admin be sent an email anyway.

How is it usually done?

Note that RabbitMQ and MySql are just examples, I might've chosen something else, I just want to know the general approach.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working in 24/7 on-call rotations and I prefer emails that tell me the exact reason why something when down.

An email telling my *system is down* is okay, but an email

> System is down, because mysql doesn't respond.
>
> You might want to check: mysql server at 1.2.3.4 for
>
> 1. is it running,
> 2. disk space,
> 3. ...

is much better and helps a lot to fix a system in short time. Therefore I think, yes an error message should be as precise als possible.

But on the other hand ensure that you do not send many different emails for the same problem that would be counterproductive.